# XSLT: From flat to hierarchic​al structure

Tags: xslt

I need to convert a flat structure like this

```
 <root>
    <H>1</H>
    <I>1-1</I>
    <I>1-2</I>
    <I>1-3</I>
    <H>2</H>
    <I>2-1</I>
    <I>2-2</I>
  </root>
```

in one like this

```
   <root>
        <H>
           1
           <I>1-1</I>
           <I>1-2</I>
           <I>1-3</I>
        </H>
        <H>
           2
           <I>2-1</I>
           <I>2-2</I>
        </H>
     </root>
```

I'm trying the approach for-each on the source structure in this way

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
     xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
 >
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="root">
       <root>
          <xsl:for-each select="child::node()">
             <xsl:if test="self::H">
                <H>
                   <xsl:copy-of select="@* | node()"/>
                   <xsl:call-template name="copyI"/>
                </H>
             </xsl:if>
          </xsl:for-each>
       </root>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="copyI">
       <xsl:for-each select="following-sibling::node()">
          <xsl:choose>

             <xsl:when test="self::H">
                <!-- Should be fantastic to exit from the loop! -->
             </xsl:when>

             <xsl:when test="self::I"
                <I>
                   <xsl:copy-of select="@* | node()"/>
                </I>
                <xsl:text>&#13;</xsl:text>
             </xsl:when>

          </xsl:choose>
       </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Unfortunately, the best result that I can reach is this

```
<root>
    <H>
       1
       <I>1-1</I>
       <I>1-2</I>
       <I>1-3</I>
       <I>2-1</I>     wrong!
       <I>2-2</I>     wrong!
    </H>
    <H>
       2
       <I>2-1</I>
       <I>2-2</I>
    </H>
 </root>
```

where       `<I>2-1</I>` and `<I>2-2</I>` under H1 are wrong.

The problem is that I cannot escape from the template copyI when it finds and H.
 Since the source structure is flat (all siblings), I'm afraid that a
 recursive copyI doesn't help.

Any suggestion?

Thanks a lot.
 Nicola

## How to extend your solution?

Tomalak, thank you very much for your help.
Really, my needs is a bit more complicated and your solution is not scalable.
In my source is optionally presents a `<C>` third level hierarchically dependent to `<I>`

```
<root>
   <H>1</H>
   <I>1-1</I>
   <C>1-1-1</C>
   <I>1-2</I>
   <C>1-2-1</C>
   <I>1-3</I>
   <H>2</H>
   <I>2-1</I>
   <I>2-2</I>
   <C>2-2-1</C>
</root>
```

and the expected output is

```
<root>
   <H>1
    <I>1-1<C>1-1-1</C></I>
    <I>1-2<C>1-2-1</C></I>
    <I>1-3</I>
   </H>
   <H>2
    <I>2-1</I>
    <I>2-2<C>2-2-1</C></I>
   </H>
</root>
```

Thanks a lot again
Nicola

Comment: As a general tip: Drop the habit of using `<xsl:for-each>`. In 95% of cases you are better off with `<xsl:apply-templates>`.

Comment: Note: you are creating a *mixed content* structure; usually, this is not such a good idea.

Comment: Do your `<H>` and `<C>` nodes *really* all contain strings like `2-2-1`? Also, your expected output makes no sense. It only has different indentation, it does not have different structure.

Comment: Sorry Tomalak. In Italy we say that "I'm stunned"! :)

Comment: Really, H, I and C doesn't contains those strings but several elements for each. This prototype structure is a simple representation of the original.

Comment: In your new output example, are you really intending to nest `C` inside of `I`? If not, you can simply change `following-sibling::I` to `following-sibling::*[not(self::H)]` in Tomalak's first XSLT.

Comment: Unfortunately yes, Daniel. Nicola

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simple:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 
  exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="H" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="H">
    <xsl:variable name="myId" select="generate-id()" />
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="text()[normalize-space() != '']" />
      <xsl:copy-of select="
        following-sibling::I[generate-id(preceding-sibling::H[1]) = $myId]
      " />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

For each `<H>` you need to copy those following `<I>` elements whose *directly preceding* `<H>` is identical to the current one (node identity is established in XSLT by comparing the results of `generate-id()`).

Output:

```
<root>
  <H>1<I>1-1</I><I>1-2</I><I>1-3</I></H>
  <H>2<I>2-1</I><I>2-2</I></H>
</root>
```

Indentation depends on the XSLT processor you use, but since insignificant whitespace is, well ... insignificant, you shouldn't worry too much about that.

---

You can achieve the same thing by using an XSL key, if you prefer that:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 
  exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:key name="kI" match="I" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::H[1])" />

  <xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="H" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="H">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="text()[normalize-space() != '']" />
      <xsl:copy-of select="key('kI', generate-id())" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The key can improve performance for large input documents.

Comment: Yes, correct. Naively, I thought that I could scalable the solution to an other level. Could you help me again? Nicola

Comment: Not without an input sample that covers your case exactly.

Comment: The case is this. Thanks a lot Tomalak                             <root>
   <H>1</H>
   <I>1-1</I>
   <C>1-1-1</C>
   <I>1-2</I>
   <C>1-1-2</C>
   <H>2</H>
   <I>2-1</I>
   <I>2-2</I>
   <C>2-2-1</C>
</root>

Comment: Please edit your question appropriately, complete with input and expected output. Posting code to the comments is useless.

Comment: @nick Please edit *your question*, not my answer. ;-)

Comment: Tomalak, I added the question. Thanks very much. Nicola